# Issues with WCF (net.tcp) hosted in IIS 7.5

Tags: wcf

I built a application with 5 wcf services and hosted them in IIS 7.5. I used the default configuration for the net.Tcp port (808*).

I am not used to host WCF services in IIS (I always hosted in Windows Services) and I found interesting that when I call the service (using tcp binding) I got two different process on the server.

One is SMSvcHost.exe (the one that is actually using the 808 port) and the other is w3wp.exe wich I think is handling a instance of the server I am calling.

I have a lot of questions so I will enumerate them:

1. Should I use IIS instead of Windows Service to host WCF Services (tcp binding) ?
2. The fact that I have two processes to answer my request means that I may have cpu impacts ?
3. Sometimes my services stop answering using the tcp binding. I got a timeout error on my clients but the mex is correctly answering if I go to the http://myServer/Service1.svc. I suspect that this problem is caused by fault connections but I am throwing exceptions correctly (using fault exceptions) and catching them correctly on my clients. Besides, I am also implementing a partial class for every service to dispose corretly (either using Close or Abort methods). Is there any way to figure out what's going on when the services stop answering ?
4. Shouldn't the w3wp.exe processes be closed after the client ends the request ? They remain on the Task Manager even when no one is using the services. I guess this is the reason of why my Entity Library logging locks the file after my request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it would be better hosted in Windows Activation Services (WAS) which is close to what you think of as IIS, but not quite. Here's a good introductory article on MSDN magazine:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx